Updating a Single Attribute in Ember-Data Model Also Resets Relationships
I'm working on an Ember.js application where I need to update a single attribute (views) on a book model using Ember Data. However, when I call save() on the model, the relationships of the book (like usersInProgress, usersReadBooks, usersToRead) are also included in the request, even though I haven't made any changes to them. This results in the relationships being reset to empty arrays on the backend.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
let bookToUpdate = await this.store.findRecord('book', book.id);
//i also tried with the peekRecord() function.
bookToUpdate.views = parseInt(bookToUpdate.views) + 1;
await bookToUpdate.save();

When this code runs, the network request sent to my API looks something like this:
{
  "data": {
    "id": "5cf2fb03-a8c6-4024-82b2-aa9855f26c83",
    "type": "books",
    "attributes": {
      "views": 314
    },
    "relationships": {
      "usersInProgress": {
        "data": []
      },
      "usersReadBooks": {
        "data": []
      },
      "usersToRead": {
        "data": []
      }
    }
  }
}

This results in the usersInProgress, usersReadBooks, and usersToRead relationships being reset on the backend, which I don't want.
I attempted to modify the model to exclude relationships in the save() request, but it didn't seem to work. I also tried to assign the previous values of the relationships before the save() function but it doesn't work.
How can I update just the views attribute of my book model without including and resetting its relationships? Is there a way to prevent Ember Data from including relationships in the save() request when they haven't been modified?

It seems that Ember Data serializes the to-many relationship even it has not been loaded before. Assuming you are using the @ember-data/serializer/json-api, the  shouldSerializeHasMany method controls if a to-many relationship is serialized. In general Ember Data is not very good at handling updates to relationships in my perspective. It does not utilize all features of JSON:API.
